# need help in tcppdf , formatting image in array

Tags: php

[image: This picture explain what I need to do]

I need to move the icon line to the same level line of the cells in the right

I tried to change Y level but all icons appear in the same coordinates.

My second question is

I need to align the multicell content in center vertically and Horizontal

also I tried the parameters from TCPPDF.org but it not work

```
$pdf->SetXY(65,170);
$pdf->SetFillColor(188,211,156);
$pdf->SetTextColor(83,95,65);

$pdf->Cell(90,7,"رموز العناية",1,1,'C',1);
  $pdf->Ln(5);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFillColor(173,243,173);
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$row['title'],1,0,'C',1); // 

$pdf->SetFillColor(233,233,233);
$pdf->MultiCell(90,10,$row['des'], 1,1,'C',1);

$pdf->Image('./assets/images/textiles_caring/' . $row['photo'], 55 , '', 10 , 10 , '', null );

    }
```